# TypeScript error: 'Property 'data' does not exist on type {}' when using the useQueries hook in React

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, react-query, tanstackreact-query

I'm using the react tankstack query for fetching data but i'm getting typescript error for the line `return item?.data?.data;` and the error is `Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'`

Here is my code

```
const useGetTaskAccordingToStatus = () => {
  const { active_project } = useSelector(projectDataInStore);
  const { total_status } = useSelector(statusDataInStore);

  const userQueries = useQueries({
    queries: total_status?.map((status: string) => {
      return {
        queryKey: [status, active_project],
        queryFn: () =>
          customAxiosRequestForGet('/task', {
            status,
            projectName: active_project,
          }),
      };
    }),
  });

  const data = useMemo(
    () =>
      userQueries?.map((item: UseQueryResult<unknown, unknown>) => {
        console.log(item, 'this is item');
        return item?.data?.data;
      }),
    [userQueries],
  );

  return { data };
};
```

and here in the attachment how the item looks like.[image]

I' don't know much about typescript so i don't know how to fix it.

I tried to using unkown type but that don't fix the error

```
userQueries?.map((item: UseQueryResult<unknown, unknown>) => {
      console.log(item, 'this is item');
      return item?.data?.data;
 }),
```

Answer (score 0):

With the type `item: UseQueryResult<T, S>` you tell the compiler that `item.data` is of type `T` and `item.error` is of type `S`. In your case `item.data` is `unknown` so you can't do `item.data?.data` since `data` doesn't exist on `unknown`. (The reason it says `{}` and not `unknown` is because you've done some narrowing with the question mark.)

The easiest way to solve this is to add the actual type of `item.data` to `UseQueryResult`. E.g. if the type is `Task`, use the type `UseQueryResult<Task, unknown>`.

However in general you wan't to declare the types as early as possible and them have TypeScript infer them.

The best way would be to declare the return type of `customAxiosRequestForGet`. If that's not possible, you can declare a return type of `queryFn`: `queryFn: (): Task =>` . Now you can remove the `UseQueryResult` type.